# <extracting data from value failed> in NSDictionary

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdictionary, xcode8, nsjsonserialization

I am stuck at a point when I convert data from web services to NSDictionary. But while accessing on console in debug mode it returns , while when i bind the values of dictionary with view it works perfectly.
Below is the code:-

```
NSDictionary *responseDict =  [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&e];
```

and at console i am using `po [dictName valueForKey:@"Status"]` as well as po `[dictName objectForKey:@"Status"]`.
Followed few steps but does not work for me
1. setting Optimization level to none already in this mode.
2.Edit scheme to debug mode already in this mode.

Comment: Have you tried printing the whole dictionary. `po responseDict`

Comment: yes whole dictionary is printing the values!!!

Comment: Search through the printed `Dict` whether it has `Status` Key.

Comment: Yes it has the key , even i tried to access some other keys as well but all are returning the same error , I am posting dict  '{
    ErrorCode = 0;
    Message = "User login successfully";
    ReviewDetail = "<null>";
    Status = 1;
    TotalRecord = 0;
    UserData =     {
        Aid = 1;
        Email = "";
        IsActive = 1;
        Name = Administrator;
        pwd = admin123;
        usid = admin;
    };
    lstReviewDetail = "<null>";
}'

Comment: What error are you getting.

Comment: <extracting data from value failed>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129593/discussion-between-new16-and-anupam-gupta).

Comment: Can you send your actual JSON.

Comment: {"Status":1,"lstReviewDetail":[{"Rid":1,"UploadDate":"Date(1480655794987+0530)","ApplicationId":1,"FolderName":"test","IsDeleted":true,"UsId":1,"FtpPath":"abc.mp3","Title":"test"},{"Rid":4,"UploadDate":"Date(1480572974807+0530)","ApplicationId":1,"FolderName":"tst","IsDeleted":false,"UsId":1,"FtpPath":"test","Title":"test"},{"Rid":5,"UploadDate":"Date(1480575760957+0530)","ApplicationId":1,"FolderName":"test","IsDeleted":false,"UsId":1,"FtpPath":"test,mp3","Title":"test"}],"UserData":null,"ErrorCode":0,"ReviewDetail":null,"TotalRecord":0,"Message":"Success"}

Comment: Well the above JSON is not proper. I corrected it, use the casting to `NSNumber` and then print `po  [((NSNumber *)[responseDict valueForKey:@"Status"]) integerValue] `.

Comment: I am having this issue as well. It may be a bug in the debugger interpreter, as my code responds with success but debugging the values gives sporadic issues.

Answer (score 1):

I meet this problem when I try to get information from `Info.plist`. Finally I use a string exchange.

```
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Info"ofType:@"plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
    NSString *version = [data objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
    self.labVersion.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)", version];
```

Comment: In addition: then you can cast string value to bool value, for example version.boolValue, or to number value, for example version.numberValue if you want, etc. Bool and may be some other types can incorrect extract from plist-dictionaries, because plist-dictionaries may be is actually have json-format; it is my supposition. String values extract perfectly, however you can see errors while extracting it for example in Xcode-console via po: (po plistDictionary[@"someKeyForExtractingStringValue"])